# Strange Django session KeyError

Tags: python, django

I am learning to use sessions in Django. Here is simple code that I wrote. It was working yesterday, however, I keep getting KeyErrors 'score' today. Where is the problem?

```
def home(request):
        request.session.get('score',0)
        if request.GET.get('add'):
            request.session['score'] += 1
        if request.GET.get('restart'):
            request.session['score'] = 0
        return render_to_response('home.html', {'zero':request.session['score']})
```

Comment: see what is the output of `request.session`?

Comment: I had the same issue with my code. It is weird though why it works in the beginning and it doesn't work after a while. No code has been changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `request.session.get('score',0)` to `request.session.setdefault('score',0)`.